# Dir walking to get abs path array of various files

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Goal: Get a List of Absolute Paths for all files in a directory recursively leveraging NodeJs.

Info: As a python dev, I normally use the python packages which handle this in a platform independent fashion.  My boss wanted some javascript code which would handle this goal... and as a JS dev previously, I was like "oh this is easy. Let's look up the node as I never got a chance to get my hands dirty with it." but I seem to be mistaken.

I don't see anything in node relating to Dir Walking, or a way I could hack together to create such a thing.

I was looking in "Child Process", "Console", "File System", "OS", "Path", and "Process".  I didn't see anything which would do anything akin to:

```
pushd .
cd $dir
for folder in $(ls);
do
  pushd .
  cd $folder
    //call again
  ls $(pwd)$flag >> $dir/files_matching.txt 
  popd
done;

 // or any platform independent means of recursively getting 
 // all files and their abs path which meet flag criterion, 
 //  such as "*.txt" || "_*found*"
```

I could use child process to carry out Command Line items, but then I need to create a bunch of conditionals based on the OS consuming the app, and figured this would be something which already exists.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but figured this has already been done; I just don't see it in the base modules.

Is there a node module I would need which accomplishes this, which is outside of the base modules?

I am trying not to have to hand roll a conditional os based system to get an exhaustive list of abs paths for all files under a directory (or subset due to extensions, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

synchronous:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { resolve } = require("path");

const getFiles = dir => {
  const stack = [resolve(dir)];
  const files = [];
  while (stack.length) {
    dir = stack.pop();
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(item => {
      const path = resolve(dir, item);
      (fs.statSync(path).isDirectory() ? stack : files).push(path);
    });
  }
  return files;
};

console.log(getFiles("."));
```

asynchronous:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { resolve } = require("path");
const pify = require("util").promisify;
const readdir = pify(fs.readdir);
const stat = pify(fs.stat);

const getFiles = async dir => {
  const files = await readdir(resolve(dir));
  const filesP = files.map(async file => {
    const path = resolve(dir, file);
    return (await stat(path)).isDirectory() ? getFiles(path) : path;
  });
  // return (await Promise.all(filesP)).flat(); // flat supported in node ~11
  return [].concat(...(await Promise.all(filesP)));
};

getFiles(".").then(console.log);
```

async demo https://repl.it/@marzelin/getFiles

Comment: I do like the stack better too.  This is far more clean than mine.  Not only did i forget ES6 code to keep things more streamlined.... but I for some reason didnt use a stack when I should have...

i just have 1 question, for sync, what is dir on the first iteration?  It looks like getFiles is a function taking a directory, but i dont see it being called.  Im guessing you are just leaving out the execution?  `getFiles("/");` for example?

Comment: @Fallenreaper yes, exactly. I've added an execution example (for the current dir `process.cwd()`) to the code.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was looking at the filesystem module and noticed the function *readDir*

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

which does the trick in part.  I guess it wasnt named a method i would have looking for.  I was looking for things involving LIST and DIR, but not READ.

Anyways, here is a way to read Dir.

```
var fs = require('fs');

if (process.argv.length <= 2) {
    console.log("Usage: " + __filename + " path/to/directory");
    process.exit(-1);
}

var path = process.argv[2];

fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
    console.log(items);

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i]);
    }
});
```

You notice that this one above is Async, but there is a Sync variant, just add "Sync" to the signature.  Now you need to determine if something is a directory:

```
let file = fs.statSync("path/to/directory")
let isDir = file.isDirectory()
```

So you can couple this all together.

```
var fs = require('fs')
function recurse_file_system(path, contains) {
  let files = fs.readdirSync(path);
  let dArr = [];
  let fArr = [];
  for (let i in files){
    let newPath = path + "/" + files[i]
    if (fs.statSync(newPath).isDirectory()){
      dArr.push(newPath)
    }else{
      if (filter(files[i], ".txt")){
         fArr.push(newPath)
      }
    }
  }
  if (arr.length == 0){
    return fArr;
  }else{
    for (let d in dArr){
      let rslt = recurse_file_system(dArr[d]);
      for (let i in rslt){
        fArr.push(rslt[i])
      }
    }
    return fArr;
  }
}
console.log("Files:")
console.log(recurse_file_system("/"))
```

Now if you want to extend this, all you need to do is add a filter to say, limit the size of returns based on particular criterion, such as file name limitation.

```
function filter(filename, contains){
   let reg = new RegEx(contains)
   return reg.test(filename)
}
```

and you can add it to the base case, where you see filter... OR you can just return the WHOLE set and filter it there with the List method, filter.